# Loop whose endpoint (?) change during the loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a loop which insert rows on specific cases. The loop goes through ~2000 rows and insert about 500.

Due to the inserted rows it doesn't loop the full range I want. I have solved that problem by counting the number of row I will insert with a first loop and then looping up to LastRow + Counter.

I feel as if there must have been a better way to do it.

```
Sub AddRows()
Dim i As Integer: i = 8
Dim LastRow As Integer: LastRow = Cells(8, 2).End(xlDown).Row
Dim counter As Integer: counter = 0

For i = 8 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i

NewLastRowAfterAddingRows = LastRow + counter  

For i = 8 To NewLastRowAfterAddingRows 
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        Range(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how** ("loop" is the latter, rather than the former). The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. The purpose of this function is to insert rows in order to do then other retreatement to the file.
My problem was : Reduce from two loop to one loop or better. 
My title is vague as I don't know the proper terms.

Comment: What do the rows *mean*?  "Rows of data" is very much a *solution space* description, but a good code review question needs a *problem space* explanation.  I'd expect to see terms like "house prices" or "particle velocities" or whatever matches the problem you're solving.

Comment: rows as in excel sheet rows.

Comment: Now i'm intrigued Solution space ? Problem Space ? What does it mean ? I'm not a proffesional of developpement. Merely a hobbyist having fun coding his accountancy retreatement.

Comment: What made you write this? What specific problem does it solve? Inserting rows is part of the solution, not the problem.

Comment: Now Im confused. I have posted whole problems here before. I was met with "Please ask for specific questions on specific blocs of code". 

If you want the context. 
The aim here is generating all the accountancy writings from an extract of a bank statement. Which I have managed to do. Now I can spend my day on reddit making it seems I work hard and fast :)

Comment: Why not loop backwards?

Comment: Did not think of that. But indeed it would have been the better choice. Now i'm fine with the Bill Hileman version. 
If anyone manage to even further reduce the complexity of the loop, I take.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not a good idea to alter the iterator variable in a for/next loop.  While your code works, it's just not a good practice.  Also, your initializing i to 8 is redundant since your loop starts at 8 as well.  Here's how I would handle it:

```
Sub AddRows()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer

    LastRow = Cells(8, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    counter = 8

    For i = counter To LastRow
        If Cells(counter, 1) <> "" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            Range(counter & ":" & counter).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```